# I have a question about the multiplicative inverse in any field.

Tags: field-theory

Does the additive identity always have no multiplicative inverse? 
(I'm talking about any field not restricted to real or complex field)

If does can someone explain me why?

Comment: If $α$ was a multiplicative inverse of $0$, then $α·0 = 1$, but also $α·0 = 0$ (which is true for all elements $a$ of the field since $a·0 = a·(0+0) = a·0 + a·0$ from which you can additively cancel $a·0$ (by adding $-a·0$ to both sides)). Hence $0 = 1$ which is not allowed by the very definition of a field.

Comment: @Does the field axiom assure that two are always different?

Comment: It should.  If you tell us the field axioms you are using, I’m sure we can point out which one assures $0 ≠ 1$.  Anyway, the only ring $R$ with one in which $0 = 1$ is $R = 0$, since $∀x ∈ R\colon x = x·1 = x·0 = 0$.

Comment: I'm not sure there are guaranteed to be axioms assuring $0 \neq 1$; it's sometimes the case that the [zero ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_ring) is allowed, which is indeed a field. Of course, it's the *only* field in which $0$ is a multiplicative unit, but it seems prudent to consider its existence.

Comment: @pjs36 The zero ring is most definitely not a field. The "field with one element" does not exist in classical algebra. I would recommend taking a look at this article http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element.

Comment: @Dalton Thank you for clarifying! I did indeed have a lapse of judgement there.

Comment: @pjs36 No problem! It happens to everyone at least once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

This is true. Suppose, to the contrary, that $F$ is a field with an invertible additive neutral element $0$. This says there is an element $a$ in $F$ for which $a0 = 1$. But $a0=0$, which follows from the ring axioms, so $1=0$, which contradicts the definition of a field.

Typically a field is defined as an integral domain for which every nonzero element has a multiplicative inverse. In turn, an integral domain is typically defined as a commutative ring with unity $1 \neq 0$ such that no divisors of $0$ exist. Here lies the contradiction.